# Why libcurl needs `CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL` option and what are side effects when it is enabled?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, curl, libcurl

I spent a lot of time to investigate why multithreaded libcurl application crashes on Linux. I saw in forums that I have to use `CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL` to bypass this problem. Ok, no problems, but are there any information what side effects can it create? If `CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL = 0` is buggy, why libcurl needs this option at all nowadays when even mobile devices have multicore processors and that is why a lot of applications use multiple threads to use this hardware multitasking support?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default the DNS resolution uses signals to implement the timeout logic but this is not thread-safe: the signal could be executed on another thread than the original thread that started it.

When libcurl is not built with async DNS support (which means threaded resolver or c-ares) you must set the `CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL` option to 1 in your multi-threaded application.

You can find more details related to this topic here:

- http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html#Multi-threading
- http://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2012-September/msg01960.html
- http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2013-03/0086.html

*Why libcurl needs this option at all nowadays?*

Mainly for legacy reasons, but also because not all applications use libcurl in a multi-threaded context.

This is still something that is actively discussed. See this [recent discussion](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2014-02/0081.html):

> libcurl has no threads on its own that it needs to protect and it doesn't know 
>   what thread library/concept you use so it cannot on its own set the callbacks. 
>   This has been the subject for discussion before and there are indeed valid 
>   reasons to reconsider what we can and should do, but this is how things have 
>   been since forever and still are. [...] but I'm always open for further discussions!